# T-SQL Merge records based on criteria

Tags: t-sql, merge, records

In SQL server 2008, I have below table Score. I want to show Score1 and Score2 together for same student. Name and Email combined uniquely identifies a student (Name or Email may be missing too, like Jack and Maya@moon.com). The expected output shown as T_Combined.

Score

```
Name    Email   Score1  Score2
John    'John@pluto.com'    75  
Peter   'Peter@pluto.com'   34  
Nina    'Nina@pluto.com'    45  
Joseph  'Joseph@pluto.com'  76  
Tom 'Tom@pluto.com' 43  
Sam 'Sam@pluto.com' 76  
Nancy   'Nancy@pluto.com'   12  
Tina    'Tina@pluto.com'    56  
John    'John@mars.com' 98  
Peter   'Peter@mars.com'    12  
Nina    'Nina@mars.com' 45  
Joseph  'Joseph@mars.com'   87  
Tom 'Tom@mars.com'  67  
Sam 'Sam@mars.com'  99  
Nancy   'Nancy@mars.com'    33  
Tina    'Tina@mars.com' 23  
John    'John@pluto.com'        86
Peter   'Peter@pluto.com'       56
Nina    'Nina@pluto.com'        98
Joseph  'Joseph@pluto.com'      78
Tom 'Tom@pluto.com'     12
Sam 'Sam@pluto.com'     45
Nancy   'Nancy@pluto.com'       76
Tina    'Tina@pluto.com'        78
John    'John@mars.com'     98
Peter   'Peter@mars.com'        45
Nina    'Nina@mars.com'     76
Joseph  'Joseph@mars.com'       12
Tom 'Tom@mars.com'      84
Sam 'Sam@mars.com'      27
Nancy   'Nancy@mars.com'        54
Tina    'Tina@mars.com'     50
Jack        10  
'Maya@moon.com'     20
```

T_Combined

```
Name    Email   Score1  Score2
John    'John@pluto.com'        86
Peter   'Peter@pluto.com'       56
Nina    'Nina@pluto.com'        98
Joseph  'Joseph@pluto.com'  78  
Tom 'Tom@pluto.com' 43  12
Sam 'Sam@pluto.com' 76  45
Nancy   'Nancy@pluto.com'   12  
Tina    'Tina@pluto.com'    56  
John    'John@mars.com' 98  
Peter   'Peter@mars.com'    12  
Nina    'Nina@mars.com' 45  76
Joseph  'Joseph@mars.com'   87  12
Tom 'Tom@mars.com'  67  84
Sam 'Sam@mars.com'  99  27
Nancy   'Nancy@mars.com'    33  54
Tina    'Tina@mars.com' 23  50
Jack        10  
'Maya@moon.com'     20
```

Many thanks

Create table Score (Name varchar(20),Email varchar(20),Score1 int,Score2 int)

insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('John','John@pluto.com',75) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Peter','Peter@pluto.com',34) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Nina','Nina@pluto.com',45) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Joseph','Joseph@pluto.com',76) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Tom','Tom@pluto.com',43) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Sam','Sam@pluto.com',76) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Nancy','Nancy@pluto.com',12) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Tina','Tina@pluto.com',56) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('John','John@mars.com',98) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Peter','Peter@mars.com',12) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Nina','Nina@mars.com',45) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Joseph','Joseph@mars.com',87) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Tom','Tom@mars.com',67) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Sam','Sam@mars.com',99) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Nancy','Nancy@mars.com',33) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score1)values('Tina','Tina@mars.com',23)

insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('John','John@pluto.com',86) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Peter','Peter@pluto.com',56) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Nina','Nina@pluto.com',98) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Joseph','Joseph@pluto.com',78) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Tom','Tom@pluto.com',12) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Sam','Sam@pluto.com',45) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Nancy','Nancy@pluto.com',76) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Tina','Tina@pluto.com',78) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('John','John@mars.com',98) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Peter','Peter@mars.com',45) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Nina','Nina@mars.com',76) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Joseph','Joseph@mars.com',12) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Tom','Tom@mars.com',84) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Sam','Sam@mars.com',27) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Nancy','Nancy@mars.com',54) 
insert into Score (Name,Email,Score2)values('Tina','Tina@mars.com',50)

insert into Score (Name,Score1)values('Jack',10) 
insert into Score (Email,Score2)values('Maya@moon.com',20)

Comment: Can you format your question better? Select the table data and use Ctrl-K to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Name, Email, isnull(SUM(Score1),'') as Score1, isnull(SUM(Score2),'') as Score2
    from Score 
    group by Name, Email
```